# Organic group membership request

Tags: organic-groups, emails, notifications

I need help setting up a notification system for when a user requests to join a group.

At the moment, when the user types in their message and click the join button, the administrator receives no email notification of a users join request.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly this feature hasn't been implemented. I'm just hiding the field with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

In OG 7.2 you need to enable Rules module then enable the two rules for "Pending" and "Active" memberships